# Rails jBuilder from GeoJSON to make another json

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, geojson, jbuilder

I'm trying to take a series of GeoJSON Line Strings and put them on a map. My jBuilder and Rails controller combination is not producing correctly formatted json for putting on a web map. Here's the relevant code.

`overview_data.json.builder`

```
json.type "FeatureCollection"
json.features @segments do |street|
  if (street.extent_json) # only if item has a line drawn
    json.type "Feature"
    json.properties do
       json.title "Was #{street.prevName} before #{street.dateEarliest} and now is #{street.currentName} #{street.dateLatest})"
    end
    json.geometry do
       # json.type "LineString"
       json.coordinates street.extent_json
    end # json.geometry
  end  # if
end # json.features
```

`overview_controller.rb`

```
class OverviewController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
  def overview_data
    @segments = Street.all
  end
end
```

`street.extent_json` as it appears in a web form and in the database (Postgres via pgAdmin)

```
    {"type":"LineString",
    "coordinates":[[-118.25712423772116,34.01007010760971],
                  [-118.25649456380442,34.01016443793837],
                  [-118.25584971702219,34.01016443793837],
                  [-118.25427932544667,34.0102021700405],
                  [-118.25213995141625,34.010227324765935]]}
```

Output as seen in `http://localhost:3000/overview/overview_data.json`. At present there are about ten items that have extent_json. Below are the first few:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Was 10th St.  before 1903 and now is part of E. 9th Place (21). 1908)"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": "{\"type\":\"LineString\",\"coordinates\":[[-118.24982816353442,34.035546195508864],[-118.25104052200915,34.03663976724366]]}"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Was 37th St before 1903 and now is part of E. 40th Place 1928)"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": "{\"type\":\"LineString\",\"coordinates\":[[-118.25712423772116,34.01007010760971],[-118.25649456380442,34.01016443793837],[-118.25584971702219,34.01016443793837],[-118.25427932544667,34.0102021700405],[-118.25213995141625,34.010227324765935]]}"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Was Brook before 1903 and now is part of S. Toluca St. (26). and second block south gone 1908)"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": "{\"type\":\"LineString\",\"coordinates\":[[-118.25862396508458,34.06087254304104],[-118.25933206826451,34.05994816216629]]}"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Was Auto Pl before 1928 and now is Commonwealth Pl and a portion abandoned 1930)"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": "{\"type\":\"LineString\",\"coordinates\":[[-118.28558737412096,34.07543021182353],[-118.28369373455645,34.07646106299854]]}"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Was 3rd St before 1921 and now is Miramar St. One block abandoned )"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": "{\"type\":\"LineString\",\"coordinates\":[[-118.26117539280003,34.05901974362122],[-118.2593849946753,34.05823410691563],[-118.25815599257271,34.05768101430694],[-118.25759459655055,34.05717191451128],[-118.25663111959356,34.05654339202722]]}"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Was Gregory Way before  and now is Gregory Way 2017)"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": "{\"type\":\"LineString\",\"coordinates\":[[-118.37295765057208,34.06188579510917],[-118.37272698059681,34.06172580874592],[-118.37264114990832,34.06161026285129],[-118.3725660480559,34.06146805230318],[-118.37253386154772,34.061414723286084],[-118.37249631062151,34.06118363049104]]}"
      }
    },
```

The problem is the added `"{\"type\":\"LineString\",\"coordinates\"` and closing `}"`. Otherwise I think it's OK.

In the jBuilder I originally had `json.type "LineString"` in the json.geometry do loop and it's even worse adding: `"geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":"{\"type\":\"LineString\",\"coordinates\"`.

As Зелёный pointed out `json.coordinates JSON.parse(street.extent_json)` replacing similar line was needed. As he also pointed out I must have had some malformed `json` inputs which I did. Once that was cleaned up everything is working.

He also pointed out "in jbuilder template all things must be in plain Ruby, but you pass a json string(which comes from database) as result Rails tried to convert json string to json again."

But output still has an error, here's the first item:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Was 10th St.  before 1903 and now is part of E. 9th Place (21). 1908)"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": {
          "type": "LineString",
          "coordinates": [
            [
              -118.24982816353442,
              34.035546195508864
            ],
            [
              -118.25104052200915,
              34.03663976724366
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    },
```

An extra `{
            "coordinates":` after `geometry`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `extent_json` method, it returns an object as json string. To resolve your issue, *avoid the double call* `to_json`.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. I'm not explicitly calling `to_json`, so where is it being called? I see `extend_json` as a field in my `streets` database. Thank you for responding.

Comment: `765: unexpected token at ':"LineString","coordinates":[[-118.23927494951936,34.00801308572366],[-118.23688905239013,34.00806596837443],[-118.23280623377325,34.008055391846895],[-118.23033102498677,34.00807654490061]]'` resulted after making the suggested change.

`street.extent_json` is` json` in the PostGIS database [edit]

Answer (score 1):

To restate the problem: take a series of GeoJSONs from a database and use jBuilder to compile all the items that meet a certain criteria into a GeoJSON (for use in a Mapbox/Leaflet web map). [https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057388/Зелёный](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057388/%D0%97%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) provided the answer offline, but I want to document it to make sure I understand it and help anyone else with a similar problem. It helps to consider the jsons as hashes and that jbuilder is making another hash.

The input has two keys: `type` and `coordinates`.

The output has keys of `type`, `properties`, and `geometry`.
The `properties` value is a key `title`; 
the `geometry` values are two keys `type` and `coordinates`. So `overview_data.json.builder` becomes:

```
extent = JSON.parse(street.extent_json) # the GeoJSON 
json.type "Feature"

json.properties do
   json.title h("Was #{street.prevName} before #{street.dateEarliest} and now is #{street.currentName} #{street.dateLatest}.")
end

json.geometry do
   json.type "LineString"
   json.coordinates extent["coordinates"]
end
```

Looks straightforward once it's laid out. Except for other key points. One was parsing `extent_json` to convert the string to a hash object. Then  `coordinates` are extracted from that hash to put into the output json.